react-hook-form -> onSubmit not responding
I am building a small application in NextJS 14 , wherein I am using react-hook-form to simplify the form submission and input handling. I am facing an issue for the last 3-4 days and have tried different ways to find the bug , but I am unable to find one. So the problem is something like this :
Following is the frontend code for the sign-up form at "/sign-up":
"use client";

import { ApiResponse } from "@/types/ApiResponse";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDebounceCallback } from "usehooks-ts";
import * as z from "zod";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { SignUpSchema } from "@/schemas/signUpSchema";

export default function SignUpForm() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [usernameMessage, setUsernameMessage] = useState("");
  const [isCheckingUsername, setIsCheckingUsername] = useState(false);
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const debouncedUsername = useDebounceCallback(setUsername, 300);

  const router = useRouter();
  const { toast } = useToast();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof SignUpSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(SignUpSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUsernameUnique = async () => {
      if (username !== "") {
        setIsCheckingUsername(true);
        setUsernameMessage("");
        try {
          const response = await axios.get<ApiResponse>(
            `/api/check-username-unique?username=${username}`
          );
          setUsernameMessage(response.data.message);
        } catch (error) {
          const axiosError = error as AxiosError<ApiResponse>;
          setUsernameMessage(
            axiosError.response?.data.message ?? "Error checking username"
          );
        } finally {
          setIsCheckingUsername(false);
        }
      }
    };
    checkUsernameUnique();
  }, [username]);

  async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof SignUpSchema>) {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/signup", data);

      toast({
        title: "Success",
        description: response.data.message,
      });

      router.replace(`/verify/${username}`);

      setIsSubmitting(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during sign-up:", error);

      const axiosError = error as AxiosError<ApiResponse>;

      let errorMessage = axiosError.response?.data.message;
      ("There was a problem with your sign-up. Please try again.");

      toast({
        title: "Sign Up Failed",
        description: errorMessage,
        variant: "destructive",
      });

      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen bg-gray-800">
      <div className="w-full max-w-md p-8 space-y-8 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
        <div className="text-center">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight lg:text-5xl mb-6">
            Join True Feedback
          </h1>
          <p className="mb-4">Sign up to start your anonymous adventure</p>
        </div>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
            <FormField
              name="username"
              control={form.control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      {...field}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        field.onChange(e);
                        debouncedUsername(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  {isCheckingUsername && <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />}
                  {!isCheckingUsername && usernameMessage && (
                    <p
                      className={`text-sm ${
                        usernameMessage === "Username is unique"
                          ? "text-green-500"
                          : "text-red-500"
                      }`}
                    >
                      {usernameMessage}
                    </p>
                  )}
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              name="email"
              control={form.control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...field} name="email" />
                  </FormControl>
                  <p className="text-muted text-black text-sm">
                    We will send you a verification code
                  </p>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              name="password"
              control={form.control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type="password" {...field} name="password" />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <Button type="submit">
              {isSubmitting ? (
                <>
                  <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
                  Please wait
                </>
             ) : (
                "Sign Up"
              )}
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
        <div className="text-center mt-4">
          <p>
            Already a member?{" "}
            <Link href="/sign-in" className="text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800">
              Sign in
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

And here is my route.ts for /api/(auth)/signup :
import { sendVerification } from "@/helpers/sendVerification";
import ConnectToDB from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import UserModel from "@/models/User";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  if (request.method !== "POST") {
    return Response.json(
      {
        success: false,
        message: `This route only accepts POST request method, received ${request.method} instead`,
      },
      {
        status: 405,
      }
    );
  }
  await ConnectToDB();
  try {
    const { email, username, password } = await request.json();
    const existingVerifiedUsernameUser = await UserModel.findOne({
      username,
      isVerified: true,
    });
    if (existingVerifiedUsernameUser) {
      return Response.json(
        {
          success: false,
          message: "username is already verified",
        },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }
    const existingUserByEmail = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    let verifyCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();

    if (existingUserByEmail) {
      if (existingUserByEmail.isVerified) {
        return Response.json(
          {
            success: false,
            message: "User already exists with this email",
          },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      } else {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        existingUserByEmail.password = hashedPassword;
        existingUserByEmail.verifyCode = verifyCode;
        existingUserByEmail.verifyCodeExpiry = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000);
        await existingUserByEmail.save();
      }
    } else {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      const expiryDate = new Date();
      expiryDate.setHours(expiryDate.getHours() + 1);

      const newUser = new UserModel({
        username,
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        verifyCode,
        verifyCodeExpiry: expiryDate,
        isVerified: false,
        isAcceptingMessages: true,
        messages: [],
      });

      await newUser.save();
    }
    const emailResponse = await sendVerification(email, username, verifyCode);
    if (!emailResponse.success) {
      return Response.json(
        {
          success: false,
          message: emailResponse.message,
        },
        { status: 500 }
      );
    }

    return Response.json(
      {
        success: true,
        message: "User registered successfully. Please verify your account.",
      },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error registering user:", error);
    return Response.json(
      {
        success: false,
        message: "Error registering user",
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

Here is my Signup schema :
import { z } from "zod";

export const usernameValidation = z
  .string()
  .min(2, "Username must be atleast 2 characters long")
  .max(20, "Username must be atmost 20 characters long")
  .regex(
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/,
    "Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores"
  );

export const SignUpSchema = z.object({
  username: usernameValidation,
  email: z.string().email("Please use a valid email address"),
  password: z.string().min(6, "Password must be atleast 6 characters long"),
  confirmPassword: z.string(),
});


The problem is, the form is not responding to the onSubmit, I have tried console logging inside the onSubmit, but the function is not getting called.
Please help me find the solution to it.

Can you please provide SignUpSchema?

@PinalTilva I have provided the schema. Please help me find the bug.

Thanks a lot @PinalTilva, your solution worked, also I was unaware that we have an optional error callback function in that handleSubmit. Thanks a lot.

Best of luck for your project, please mark my answer with green tick than :)

You have to make your confirmPassword ( in your schema ) an optional field as below:
export const SignUpSchema = z.object({
  username: usernameValidation,
  email: z.string().email("Please use a valid email address"),
  password: z.string().min(6, "Password must be atleast 6 characters long"),
  confirmPassword: z.string().optional(),
});

You can check the error that occurred while submitting by placing a log as below:
// ...
<form
  onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, (error) => {
    console.log(error, "error");
  })}
  className="space-y-6"

// ....

Here you can learn more
